# PHP: manipulate array making value as key recursively

Tags: php, arrays

I got this array:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:7 [▼
     "id" => "1"
     "producer" => "Samsung"
     "model" => "LE22B541C4W"
     "category" => "1"
     "production_date" => "2009-05-08"
     "status" => "Discontinued"
     "type" => "LCD"
     ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:7 [▼
     "id" => "2"
     "producer" => "Samsung"
     "model" => "P24FHD"
     "category" => "1"
     "production_date" => "0000-00-00"
     "status" => "Discontinued"
     "type" => "LCD"
    ]
  ]
 [...]
]
```

I would like to take the "ID" value of each array and make as primary key and remove the useless keys like this

```
array:2 [
  1 => array:7 [
    "id" => "1"
    "producer" => "Samsung"
    "model" => "LE22B541C4W"
    "category" => "1"
    "production_date" => "2009-05-08"
    "status" => "Discontinued"
    "type" => "LCD"
    ]
  2 => array:7 [
   [...]
```

By now I'm just populate the array using this simple query and a for loop:

```
foreach ($compatibility as $compElement) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE ID = '$compElement';";

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $thisElement = $stmt->fetchAll();

        $compArray[] = $thisElement;

    }
```

Comment: `$compArray[$thisElement['id']] = $thisElement;`

Comment: I got this `array:1 [▼
  "" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => "2"
      "producer" => "Samsung"
      "model" => "P24FHD"
      "category" => "1"
      "production_date" => "0000-00-00"
      "status" => "Discontinued"
      "type" => "LCD"
    ]
  ]
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this if you don't want to change how you populate your array:

```
$result = call_user_func_array(
               'array_merge_recursive',
                $array
            );
```

Output

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["producer"]=>
    string(7) "Samsung"
    ["model"]=>
    string(11) "LE22B541C4W"
    ["category"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["production_date"]=>
    string(10) "2009-05-08"
    ["status"]=>
    string(12) "Discontinued"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "LCD"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["producer"]=>
    string(7) "Samsung"
    ["model"]=>
    string(6) "P24FHD"
    ["category"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["production_date"]=>
    string(10) "0000-00-00"
    ["status"]=>
    string(12) "Discontinued"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "LCD"
  }
}
```

Comment: I only got `array:7 [▼
  "id" => "2"
  "producer" => "Samsung"
  "model" => "P24FHD"
  "category" => "1"
  "production_date" => "0000-00-00"
  "status" => "Discontinued"
  "type" => "LCD"
]` where I'm wrong?

Comment: Show full code, it looks like you can be calling it more then once.